# Why is the input type="date" field 2 pixels taller than input type="text" fields in Chrome?

Tags: input, textfield, styling, datefield

I have an input type="date" field side-by-side with an input type="text" field in Chrome.  The input date field is 2 pixels taller than the text field. Does anyone know why this happens? After viewing [this page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/bl_input-tag-examples.htm#date), it appears to happen regardless of styling.

Comment: If anyone can provide a solution for making them equal heights, that would help greatly.

Comment: Could you please post whatever CSS you have attached to those fields?

Comment: Well this link, http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/bl_input-tag-examples.htm#date, shows it without styling so that it's easier to see.

Comment: Here's another simpler example: http://jsfiddle.net/1cc4whfj/1/

Answer (score 2):

This probably goes without saying, but since it hasn't been mentioned here yet... Setting explicit heights on `date` and the other inputs you want to match, will make this a non-issue.

Just spent quite a bit of time looking into this and unfortunately haven't found any other way around it.

And then another issue shows up: It seems the native stepper doesn't automatically align it'self to vertical center.

I tried using `display: flex; align-items: center;` on the input (to no affect) but finally, directly targeting the spinner with `::-webkit-inner-spin-button` and applying `align-self: center;` took care of it.

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="date"] {
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  padding-right: .5rem;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Text</span>
  <input type="text">
</label>

<label>
  <span>Date</span>
  <input type="date">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's less-than-ideal, but I ended up just styling the `padding` property for my`input[type="date"]` differently than for my `input`.

```
input, select, textarea {

    padding: 3px 5px;

    /* Fix for input and select elements being different sizes */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

input[type="date"] 
{
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

Note that I also account for the select element's height inconsistency, which is fixed with the `box-sizing` property. You may encounter this as well.

Comment: This will make the input smaller non WebKit browsers.